# Change Disqus Icon / favicon

Tags: favicon, disqus

I have been trying for several weeks to change the icon of Disqus.

I mean the favicon, is possibile?

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8cbxom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favicons for a Disqus forum (based on it's shortname) can be generated using the following URL:

```
https://disqus.com/api/forums/favicons/{forum_shortname}.jpg
```

Source: https://disqus.com/api/docs/images/

Comment: how? disquss is a embed

Comment: Disqus pulls the image from the site's favicon which is defined in your site's source code. If your favicon new or is updated, it may take a while for Disqus to recognized the update. So generate yor new favicon, upload it and then just wait a while. Oh, and the favicons are cached so clear your cache.

Comment: mmm i wait 3 month, I have seen many websites with this problem. it is possible disquss give the favicon only to popular community?

Comment: you should contact them if you have followed the steps and are still having problems